# How to circumvent 'name already defined error' in mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, typechecking, python-typing

So I'm doing type annotations on some code. And this code follows the following convention.

I have some kind of base module that defines certain classes

```
#module1.py
class A():
  attr1 = 'hello'
  attr2 = 'world'

class B():
  attr3 = 'hi'
  attr4 = 'earth'
```

And then in some other modules, I import and inherit from them and override some of the attributes.

```
#module2.py
from module1 import *
class A(A):
  attr1 = 'bye'

class B(B):
  attr3 = 'goodbye'
```

When I run mypy against this, it will have the following error: `Name 'A' already defined (possibly by an import)`

Is there any way I can go about fixing this without adding `# type: ignore` to each instance of this error that comes up in mypy? The only other solution I could think of is to rename the base class, e.g. `class ABase():`, but that is not possible. Because in some modules, A will not be overwritten but I still need access to A from that module. E.g. module3 might be

```
from module1 import *
class B(B):
  attr3 = 'something'
```

So here, I don't override A, but I still need to be able to access `module3.A.attr1`, which is not possible if I rename the base class. Is this possible, or should I just resort to ignoring all the errors. And if so, is there a single configuration setting I can add to my mypy.ini? I couldn't find any [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#inverting-option-values).

Comment: btw doing wildcard imports almost always is a bad idea

Comment: Yeah I know, but that's how the code was written....

Comment: set the code on fire and bury it in the woods IMO.  There are a LOT of red flags even in this very small snippet you've shared; if I were given this code to maintain I'd be doing either a major refactor or a complete rewrite before doing anything else.

Answer (score 3):

Try defining an alias for the base classes:

```
from module1 import A as ABase

class A(ABase):
    ...
```

But you should probably just change the names of the classes if you can.

Comment: The problem with this is that there are like 50 classes I'm importing from that base module, so that would be a lot of extra import statements. Probably going to go with explicitly ignoring the errors if this is the only way, but thanks...

Comment: @fooiey: you can import module instead like `import module1` and after that use `class A(module1.A): ...`

Comment: @fooiey The wildcard import is a bad practice anyway. It is weird that you have 50 classes in a module, that you need to import 50 classes, and that you need to inherit classes with the same name. I would suggest refactoring your project so there is a better solution for all this.

Answer (score 2):

[@YevhenKuzmovych's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66895553/96588) is the quickest one; another alternative would be to rename either the parent or child class. Having two different classes of the same name in the same context can't be good, and is likely to cause hard-to-debug issues down the line:

- When you see an `A` in isolation you don't know which `A` it is.
- The two `A`s must have different semantics, or they would be a single class. So there is no way to tell from the code whether one class or the other was *intended* with a quick inspection.

Ignore this warning at your peril.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error was caused by a Pydantic Class where two fields had the same alias.